# Parse XML in SQL Server 2016 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have the following xml that is stored in a database.

```
<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="PubMed-not-MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">31406890</PMID>
        <Article PubModel="Electronic-eCollection">
            <Abstract>
                <AbstractText Label="Objective" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">This study ....</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="Method" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">A purposive ....</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="Results" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">The data showed ....</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="Conclusion" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">Targeted measures ....</AbstractText>
            </Abstract>
        </Article>
     </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>
```

and I pull the data out to put into a data base using

```
insert into [Publication.PubMed.Abstract] (pmid, label, NlmCategory, Abstract  )        
    select * 
    from 
        (select distinct 
             pmid, 
             nref.value('@Label', 'varchar(max)') Label,   
             nref.value('@NlmCategory', 'varchar(max)') NlmCategory, 
             nref.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AbstractText 
         from 
             [Publication.PubMed.AllXML] a
         cross apply 
             x.nodes('//MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/AbstractText') as R(nref)
         where 
             a.pmid = @pmid ) t
```

My question is how can I make sure that my records are in the same order? The label will not always be the same, but the order of publication needs to be displayed as it is in the XML. When I insert the records it seems that they are in a random order.

Comment: You need an attribute or node you can sort on in the XML. Do you have one? And what is considered a publication? An "Article"? An "Abstract"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to simulate a sequential order of XML elements by using what is called **Node Comparison operation**. Because you didn't provide a DDL and sample data population, here is an example of how to implement it for your case. You would need to add one additional column to the DB table to store it and use it to ORDER BY it.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="PubMed-not-MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">31406890</PMID>
        <Article PubModel="Electronic-eCollection">
            <Abstract>
                <AbstractText Label="Objective" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">This study ....</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="Method" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">A purposive ....</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="Results" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">The data showed ....</AbstractText>
                <AbstractText Label="Conclusion" NlmCategory="UNASSIGNED">Targeted measures ....</AbstractText>
            </Abstract>
        </Article>
    </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>';

SELECT nref.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT') AS [AbstractNbr]
    , nref.value('@Label','varchar(max)') AS [Label]
    , nref.value('@NlmCategory','varchar(max)') AS [NlmCategory]
    , nref.value('.','varchar(max)') [AbstractText] 
FROM @xml.nodes('/PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/Abstract/AbstractText') as R(nref)
```

> [image: Output in SSMS]

Comment: That works great-  Interesting statement about DDL-  I've worked for close to 15 years reading the XML and I don't think a DDL has ever been provided. I do know that the structure of the XML file has changed many time over the years and normally I find out because something breaks. This comes from a governmental API system

Comment: It is a best practice to have an XSD contract between system of origin (sender) and system of destination (receiver). This way invalid XML data feeds are not leaving system of origin.